# Using Reactive Extensions for .NET instead of the following 'Run if not Running' pattern

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Say I have an Async call that I want to invoke, and if the call is already running, don't do anything.

In Normal C# I might write the following (ignoring the thread safety issues for a moment)

```
private bool aysncHappening = false;
private DoWorkInBgThread()
{
  if(asyncHappening)
  {
    return;
  }
  asyncHappening = true;

  RunMeOnABackgroundThread += ()=> 
  { 
    try
    {
       someWorkHere;
    }
    finally
    {
       asyncHappening = false;
    }
  };
}
```

How can I achieve the same, `Execute if Not already running`, with Rx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question, as phrased, doesn't lend itself to a satisfactory answer. 
Rx is built for situations that have streams of events or data which need to be coordinated. For fire and forget scenarios, it's not as strong. That said, here's an approach

```
bool inProgress = false;
var obsvr = Observer.Create<Unit>((x) => 
{
    if (!inProgress)
    {
        inProgress = true;
        Scheduler.ThreadPool.Schedule(() => { 
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            "InBackground".Dump(); 
            inProgress =false;
        });
    }
});

obsvr.OnNext(Unit.Default);
obsvr.OnNext(Unit.Default);
obsvr.OnNext(Unit.Default);
"main".Dump();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
obsvr.OnNext(Unit.Default);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So Rx isn't necessarily a way to handle async calls differently?

Comment: @Alan - it is, but you've only asked for one very specific form of async call